# Wireshark TLS communication shows green HTTP packets when using CCProxy proxy server?

Tags: proxy, http, ssl, wireshark, tls

Client <--> CCProxy <--> Server

I have IE configured to use a proxy server for HTTP and Secure connections. I also have a proxy server is set up with CCProxy. It is my understanding that CCProxy cannot be configured with its own certificate and private key. I used IE to connect to an HTTPS website and captured it with Wireshark. The captured packets for the Client<-->CCProxy communication show the TLS handshake and Application Data as green packets. The Packet Detail window shows both Hypertext Transfer Protocol and Secure Socket Layer rows for these packets. Following the stream shows that the data is still encrypted.

For comparison, I have an Apache proxy server that is configured with its own certificate and private key. That Wireshark capture shows grey packets for Client<-->Apache TLS communication and the Packet Detail window only shows Secure Socket Layer.

Can someone please explain why the TLS communication with CCProxy shows the packets as green HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the extra HTTP layer in the frame was because it was connecting over port 8080, so Wireshark assumed there was HTTP in the connection.